# Копирование при нажатии на кнопку мыши

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Как реализовать копирование из одного поле в другое я знаю-для этого нужно в поле ввести "что-нибудь" и произойдёт дублирование в другое поле.
А как реализовать тоже самое дублирование, но при нажатии на кнопку мыши?

Скрипт,но у меня работает при вводе "чего-нибудь" в поле

```
< script >
 onload = function() {
   document.getElementById('res2').oninput = function() {
     document.getElementById('res21').value = this.value;
     document.getElementById('res3').oninput = function() {
       document.getElementById('res31').value = this.value;
       document.getElementById('res4').oninput = function() {
         document.getElementById('res41').value = this.value;
       }
     }
   }
 } < /script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ из комментария:

Вместо `oninput` используйте `onclick`